# I get the empty set when using the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, set

I know this must be something very basic, but I dont know why I keep getting an empty set. What should I do in order to not get an empty set?

```
s=set()
for a in [(1,2),(1,3),(1,2)]:
       b=[]
       for j in range(len(a)-1):
           b.append(a)
       s.union(b)
print(s)
```

I get:

```
 s=([])
```

but the result I want is

```
{(1,2),(1,3)}
```

I know there is another way to take the union, but I wish to do so with this for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
s = set()
s = s.union([(1,2),(1,3),(1,2)])
```

set.union doesn't modify the set, so you need to save the result

if you want to use a for-loop, as you did in your post, then make sure to save the result of the union: `s = s.union(b)`

Answer (score 2):

The function `union` returns a set that is the union of `s` with `b`, you should change your code to:

```
s = set()
for a in [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2)]:
    b = []
    for j in range(len(a) - 1):
        b.append(a)
    s = s.union(b)
print(s)
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```

As an alternative you can use the `update` function:

```
s.update(b)
```

**Output**

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need the `union` method if you want to union two non-empty sets. Since you start with an empty set, you can simply use the `set` constructor:

```
s = set([(1,2),(1,3),(1,2)])
```

and `s` would become:

```
{(1, 2), (1, 3)}
```